# Laravel: How to hide/make user id uneditable in JS when using Brain Socket

Tags: javascript, php, sockets

I have a universal `used_id` that will be used in brain socket (https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket) in Laravel like this:

`window.userId = {{ $user->id }};`

This will be used when receiving notifications,messages,etc. Problem is, since it is JS, `window.userId` can be edited in the DOM (like using firebug). So the user can get notifications from other users, which should not be.

Are there any countermeasures for this? (I'm using Sentry Package to get the user id)

- I've been thinking to use unique channels for each user instead, based on their ID, but will that be overkill? And i still have no idea how to do this in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent users to edit javascript. You should use a specific kind of ID that we name "token", it's a key with a lot of every character, it's prevent users to guess the token of an other user.

You have "uniquid" who return a unique string, based on time, it can be guessed, but you can use it to assert unicity of your token. You can add informations such as user id, name, random string, maybe some salt, and then hash it.

You can use hash function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

or mcrypt (you'd better use this one) :
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php